# Impossible to create a migration with Entity Framework tools, getting error: Object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have created a project in .NET 8 and transferred all models and data context to `<project>.Data`. I have done this before but this time when trying to create the first migration with

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project Angafu.Data I
```

I get this:

```
Using assembly 'Angafu.Data'.
Using startup assembly 'Angafu.Data'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\moham\source\repos\angafu\Angafu.Data\bin\Debug\net8.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\moham\source\repos\angafu\Angafu.Data'.
Using root namespace 'Angafu.Data'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\moham\source\repos\angafu\Angafu.Data\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Found IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation 'ApplicationDbContextFactory'.
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Angafu.Data'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.  
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using DbContext factory 'ApplicationDbContextFactory'.
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Angafu.Data'...
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'Angafu.Data'...
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Angafu.Data'...
No design-time services were found.
'ApplicationDbContext' disposed.
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Initialize(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping, Boolean isNullable, IEnumerable`1 migrationsAnnotations, Boolean inline)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.InitializeColumnHelper(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, Boolean inline)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IColumn source, IColumn target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(ITable source, ITable target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have been trying tens of different solutions including updating several packages but still no luck.

I have updated `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and installed `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` which were supposed to help EF tools to find the `ApplicationDbContextFactory` class but somehow it does not work.